# How can I set the range for Xbox One controller Triggers using Pygame?

Tags: python, linux, arduino, pygame, raspberry-pi

I am using Pygame 1.9.2 with Python 3.4 to create a control program for a robot.  The controller is a new Xbox One controller connected via USB which is working fine with pygame. The problem is that the trigger buttons are considered Axes which give values from -1 to 1 depending on how hard you press.  Is there a way to change this to a range from 0 to 1 or any other range that does not include negative numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(x + 1.0) / 2.0` where `x` is whatever you get from the controller should give you a range of 0..1 (the `+ 1.0` is to get you in the range `0..2`)

Comment: >>> x = -0.83
>>> y = (2.0 - (x + 1.0)) / 2
>>> print (y)
0.915

Comment: Do you happen to know why the values default to 0.5 at the start though?